# Jenkins and PATH

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, path, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I am using Jenkins and it runs a script that uses AWS command line tools.
Because Jenkins doesn't use a shell like a normal user, it will fail saying "EC2_HOME" not set. Now I know how to set this for a regular user but not for Jenkins.
Currently I have the EC2_HOME and keys exporting in my script that Jenkins uses but I don't feel comfortable having that info in my script.

How/where can I edit Jenkin's PATH to use the EC2 tools?
I already edited /etc/profile. This was working until the server rebooted recently.

Comment: What does your build step that calls the AWS tools look like ? Is it an "execute shell" step ?

Comment: It calls a script: /opt/name-of-script.sh ARG1 ARG2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Injecting Environment variable, so you can set up all env related variables and consisting across job

See more here at plugin doc: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin